# Найти слова, содержащие не менее трех букв из первого и указать после них найденные буквы

Tags: pascal

Помогите сделать последнее задание на паскале или хотя бы подскажите, каким образом это можно реализовать.
Условие:

> В текстовом файле input.txt записан русский многострочный текст. Найти в тексте слова, содержащие не менее трех букв из первого слова текста, записать их заглавными буквами и указать после каждого такого слова в скобках найденные буквы. Полученный текст записать в файл output.txt. Весь текст, кроме найденных слов, должен остаться неизменным, включая и знаки препинания.

Мне сказали, что примерно это делается так: файл ввода считывается посимвольно, если символ находится в алфавите (русские буквы + знаки препинания), то этот символ сразу же пишется в файл вывода. При этом по ходу надо выделять слова для проверки на соответствие условию, и в скобочках после нужного слова записывать совпавшие буквы). Главная проблема в том, что при посимвольном считывании я даже не знаю, как выделить буквы из первого слова. Поэтому я считываю каждую строку текста, разбираю его на слова, которые добавляю в массив, и т.д. Программа вроде как выдает какой-то результат, но я очень сомневаюсь в его правильности.
Вот моя программа: http://ideone.com/eIQIqO
Помогите сделать ее так, как мне порекомендовали. Думаю, это самый универсальный способ, такая программа обработает любой текст со строками любой длины.

Answer (score 1):

А где проблема? В принципе, вы всё делаете правильно.

Единственное подозрительное место -- в GetWords: вы уверены, что `a[n]:=a[n]+s[i];` в конце нужно? По-моему, нет. И проверка `if _word <> ' '` вроде бы избыточна.

Подход с чтением посимвольно кажется мне излишне сложным, хотя тоже имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: >a[n]:=a[n]+s[i]; 
Добавил потому, что без этой строчки не копировался в output последний знак препинания. Как сделать без нее - не знаю, но с этой строчкой код выглядит менее красивым и раздражает. 
А в своем решении я очень сомневаюсь - достаточно скинуть в файл input текст задачи, добавив перед всем текстом слово "аутпут", например (слово В слишком короткое), как получается странный результат. Например, повторяющиеся буквы в скобках - хотя не знаю, допустимо ли это или нет. И если одна строка будет больше 255 символов, программа рухнет.

Comment: @typemoon: насчёт 255 символов не обращайте внимания, для учебного задания сойдёт, это ограничение языка.

Comment: @typemoon: повторяющиеся буквы в скобках вроде бы тоже не проблема. Хотя это смотря как интерпретировать задание, конечно. А в чём проблема с "В"? В нём не должно быть 3-х букв, а что получается на выходе? (У меня нет компилятора Паскаля под рукой, а для ideone ваш код оказался не по зубам.)

Comment: А какой примерно должен быть алгоритм при посимвольном считывании? У меня дальше этого дело не пошло:
http://ideone.com/TS9tN8
К тому же тут почему-то никогда не выполняется строка вывода неалфавитных символов. Должно быть так: если символ есть в алфавите, запускается алгоритм сборки слова, иначе (если символ не в алфавите), он просто пишется в файл. Мне кажется, это потому, что где-то лишний раз выполняется read(input, c).

Comment: С буквой В, вроде, работает:
>в ТЕВКСТОВВОМ (ввв) файле инпут записан русский многострочный текст. Найти в тексте слова, содержащие не менее трех букв из первого слова текста, записать их заглавными буквами и указать после каждого такого слова в СВКОВБКАХВ (ввв) найденные буквы.  Полученный текст записать в файл аутпут.  Весь текст, кроме найденных слов, должен остаться НВЕИЗВМЕННЫВМ (ввв) включая и знаки препинания. 
 
Но боюсь, что надо иметь хотя бы три различных буквы, а для этого еще организовывать цикл по словам.

Comment: @typemoon: ну, в задании не говорилось про _различные_ буквы. Если хотите различные, из каждого слова составьте множество букв, и проверяйте, чтобы пересечение с first содержало по крайней мере 3 элемента.

А как не работает? Дайте пример.

Comment: @typemoon: для посимвольного считывания например так: (1) Читать символы и накапливать их в first до первой не-буквы. Прочитанные символы выводить (возможно, преобразовав в заглавные) (2) Дальше читать символы по одному. Помнить текущий режим: слово или не-слово. В режиме "слово" не выводить символы, а запоминать на будущее. Если придёт не-буква или конец файла, переключиться в режим "не-слово", проверить множество символов только что оконченного слова, и вывести их (может быть, преобразовав в заглавные). В режиме "не-слово" просто выводить символы. Если придёт буква, перейти в режим "слово".